# Picking specific parts out of a query string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, query-string

I have a query string which has more than one value being passed through it and I need to access the second passed value... I have this as of now:

```
If Request.QueryString("ANBOS") IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
            Dim index As Integer = url.IndexOf("-")

            If index > 0 Then

                url = url.Substring(0, index)

            End If

            DBTable = MaterialStuff.GetComponentsForMaterial(CInt(Request.QueryString(url)))
```

I'm attempting here to dumb everything after the first value I need, then go back and look at the query string where it's equal to `ANBOS` and get its value, but when I go get the value of it, the whole query string is still there, both values...

How do I make it so I just get the first value? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Edit: Query String being passed through

```
Response.Redirect("Edit.aspx?ANBOS=" & CType(flxSearchResults.SelectedItem.Cells(1).Text, Integer) & "MaterialNumberToUpdate=" & NextMaterialID)
```

Comment: `Request.QueryString("ANBOS")` gives you the value of `ANBOS` from the Query String. That's how you get the value. You don't need to manually parse values out.

Comment: But since I'm passing more than value through the query, it returns everything after what `ANBOS` is equal too

Comment: That's not how Request.QueryString works. It only gives you the value for the specified key. They key/value pairs should be separated by an ampersand (&) sign. Perhaps you have a bad query string, please update your question to include an example.

Comment: @mason I added what my query string is in the edit

Comment: You're generating your query string incorrectly. You need to use the ampersand **within the string** to separate the key value pairs (as I described above).

Comment: Ahhh I see what you mean, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query string is being generated incorrectly

```
Response.Redirect("Edit.aspx?ANBOS=" & CType(flxSearchResults.SelectedItem.Cells(1).Text, Integer) & "MaterialNumberToUpdate=" & NextMaterialID)
```

should be..

```
Response.Redirect("Edit.aspx?ANBOS=" & CType(flxSearchResults.SelectedItem.Cells(1).Text, Integer) & "&MaterialNumberToUpdate=" & NextMaterialID)
```

This is because the query string uses ampersand signs (&) to separate key value pairs.